# How to nested sum in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this scheme:

```js
[{
        name: 'John',
        plays: [{
                playNum: 1,
                song: {
                    length: 400,
                    param: 'a'
                }
            }, {
                playNum: 2,
                song: {
                    length: 350,
                    param: 'a'
                }
            }, {
                playNum: 3,
                song: {
                    length: 211,
                    param: 'a'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'John',
            plays: [{
                    playNum: 2,
                    song: {
                        length: 400,
                        param: 'a'
                    }
                }, {
                    playNum: 3,
                    song: {
                        length: 350,
                        param: 'a'
                    }
                }, {
                    playNum: 4,
                    song: {
                        length: 211,
                        param: 'a'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I want to calculate the time of specific play
i.e. for play 2 - we have one song in 350 and another one in 400 = 750.

I tryied to do it that way:

```js
aggregate(
        {$match : { "shows.showNum" : showNum } },
        {$unwind : "$shows"},
        {$group : {_id : "$shows.showNum", totalLength : { $sum : "$shows.song.length" }}})
```

But in that way I am getting the total of all songs of player who plays in that show.

can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You use `shows` and `shownum` to aggregate. Do you mean plays and playnum ? `show` and `shownum` are not present in your schema. And for me in those plays, you have three songs so the result is 400+350+211=961.

Answer (score 3):

Your first [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) only matches the "documents" that contain that value within the array. To actually "filter" the array contents you need another [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) after you [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in the pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "plays.playNum" : playNum } },
    { "$unwind": "$plays"},
    { "$match": { "plays.playNum" : playNum } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : "$plays.playNum", 
        "totalLength": { "$sum" : "$plays.song.length" }
    }}
])
```

If you have MongoDB 2.6 or greater you can actually filter the array using the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator and other helper operators:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "plays.playNum" : playNum } },
    { "$project": {
        "plays": {
             "$setDifference": [
                {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$plays",
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.playNum", playNum ] },
                                "$$el",
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$plays" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id" : "$plays.playNum", 
        "totalLength": { "$sum" : "$plays.song.length" }
    }}
])
```

Which makes things a bit faster by combining functions from various stages. It looks more complicated but is actually the fastest way to process to the end result.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$plays'}, 
    {$match: {"plays.playNum" : 2} },
    {$group: {
        _id: null, 
        "suma": {$sum: "$song.length" }
    }}
])
```